# After I deployed my vite app on netlify it says Unexpected Application Error! e.map is not a function

Tags: netlify

[here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWl2D.png)
link to my repo https://github.com/Demzi1/Blog

I tried adding netlify.toml files for redirects but  still it didn't work. I have run out of ideas cause I have deployed before this is  the first time I have encountered this error. Please help